# Error when migrating web.xml from Java EE 5 to Java EE 6

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml

I am experiencing problems with my app since I migrated web.xml from Java-EE-5 to Java-EE-6. Here is the stacktrace I get when I deploy my app:

```
24 août 2011 14:10:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
GRAVE: Erreur lors du déploiement du descripteur de configuration ROOT.xml
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport12 cannot access its superclass javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:1948)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1911)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1800)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1768)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1377)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:856)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:353)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
24 août 2011 14:10:47 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
```

header from web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
```

ROOT.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="/home/julien/Documents/jeanbaptistemartin.com/java/site/jeanbaptistemartin/target/ROOT" path="/ROOT"/>
```

Comment: What's the version of tomcat, can you post the content of ROOT.xml, what exactly did you do when migrating from EE5 to EE6?

Comment: How does the web.xml look like - especially the header defining the namespaces?

Comment: Here is what I undertook for the migration: 1) change the header in web.xlm, 2) change the "provided" maven dependency to: <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: What server are you using? Tomcat 7 supports Servlet 3.0, but older versions doesn't.

Comment: I use tomcat 7. Here is the answer to my question: http://frazedjava.blogspot.com/2011_05_01_archive.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](http://frazedjava.blogspot.com/2011_05_01_archive.html) (in a comment above by @balteo) has the answer:

Add metadata-complete="true" in your web.xml to override default properties of 3.0 for annotations. By default, Tomcat 7 will scan all of your class files for annotations and attempt to deploy any classes found with web descriptors it understands. Setting metadata-complete tells tomcat that the web.xml and other descriptor files are complete, and not to bother with the annotations.

This solution seems to work, but it doesn't really satisfy me, because I have been deploying the same war on multiple tomcat 7 servers without a problem, but when we finally deployed to production we got this error. I'm still unsure why our production server would be any different from the test servers.