# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport12 cannot access its superclass javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I am using spring+maven. I am deploying my application in tomcat server. All of a sudden when I try to run my application I am geeting the following error.

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.16
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport12 cannot access its superclass javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:1948)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1911)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1800)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1768)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

and also the **Tomcat Server does not start.**

This is my pom.xml file

```
<properties>
        <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
        <spring.framework.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.10.Final</hibernate.version>
        <sl4j.version>1.7.2</sl4j.version>
                </properties>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <!--***************POSTGRES DEPENDENCIES***************-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--***************HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES***************-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--***************JAVAX DEPENDENCIES***************-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->

    <!--***************ASPECTJ DEPENDENCIES***************-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--***************OTHER DEPENDENCIES***************-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tcs.com.prime</groupId>
            <artifactId>PrimeLEHS</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0_rc11</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--***************TEST DEPENDENCIES***************-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Plese help me out. I am in deep struggle. Thanks

Comment: change for jdk versions and if jars are compliant to this version or not

Comment: I didnt change the jdk versions. The same project was running yesterday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This blog post](http://frazedjava.blogspot.com/2011_05_01_archive.html)  has the answer:

Add `metadata-complete="true"` in your `web.xml` to override default properties of 3.0 for annotations. By default, Tomcat 7 will scan all of your class files for annotations and attempt to deploy any classes found with web descriptors it understands. Setting metadata-complete tells tomcat that the `web.xml` and other descriptor files are complete, and not to bother with the annotations.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175250/error-when-migrating-web-xml-from-java-ee-5-to-java-ee-6)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error due to some issue in Mockito test, adding this solves the problem.

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "javax.management.*"})
```

reference: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1562

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with Tomcat Servlet 3.0 support in <7.0.15. Upgrading to a later version should resolve this issue.

Source: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51278

Comment: It seems that 7.0.22 doesn't address this issue.